# Javascript destructuring and function as an object

Tags: javascript

Could someone possibly help me understand this function and destructuring a little better?

```
export default ({ names }) => {
  const { 
      people: { 
          children = [] 
        } = {} 
    } = names;
  children.find((child) => child.email);
};
```

I understand that names is being destructured to extract data stored in objects in order to find the first child in the children's array that has an email address. But what I don't understand is why is this function declared like this ({ names })? Is it because names is an object? Sorry if this is a silly question but I am struggling to understand this.

Comment: the function expects an object that has `names` property

Comment: This means that the function expects the function argument to be an object that contains a property named `name`. See: [MDN - unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter)

Comment: `({ names })` as a parameter behaves the same as if `(obj)` was the parameter list, which was subsequently destructured with `const { names } = obj;`, which is the same as `const names = obj.names;` (however, in your code, `obj` won’t exist). First the parameter destructures the argument, then the `const` declaration destructures the rest. This may be limited example code, because it’s weird to destructure one bit in one place and another bit in another place, instead of all at once in one place.

Comment: @SebastianSimon The author may not have wanted to put that complex nested destructuring pattern in the argument list, as it would be even more confusing.

Comment: Unrelated: it's not doing anything with the result of `children.find()`. Is there a missing `return` statement?

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me everyone, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down:

- Your function takes in 1 parameter which is an object...
- ...that object must have a property `names`.

Then the function destructures the object as follows (`const { people: { children = [] } = {} } = names;`):

- First, you destructurize a property called `people` from the `names` argument
- If `people` doesn't exist, it takes the default value of `{}`.
- And finally, it grabs the property `children` (which are an array of
  objects) from its parent `people`.

Next, the function logic with [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

- All it does is searching for a *`child`* from `children` from `people` from `names` from the argument object that has a property `email`...
- ...and `return`s it. Unfortunately that part is missing in your function code.

So in your snippet, the function actually does absolutely nothing, except to be unnecessarily complicated :P

---

To wrap things up. This is what your argument to the function could look like:

```
const argument = {
  names: {
    people: {
      children: [{ email: "myemail@mail.com", name: "thechildtobefound" }],
    }
  }
};
```

And here's a working sample to try:

```js
const func = ({ names }) => {
  const { people: { children = [] } = {} } = names;
  return children.find((child) => child.email);
};

const argument = {
  names: {
    people: {
      children: [{ email: "myemail@mail.com", name: "thechildtobefound" }],
    },
  },
};

console.log(func(argument));
```

Comment: Wow, thank you @Behemoth, this explained it better than I expected, thank you for breaking it down so clearly.